# Facebook Privacy Settings for Live Streams created via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming

I am creating a live stream on facebook via the API. The request body includes a privacy parameter. I am passing the following:

```
{
  value: 'EVERYONE',
  networks: 1
}
```

However, the stream when created, is set to "friends only" and not "public". Moreover, it seems this stream is not visible to *all* friends - we have not been able to figure out what cases work.

When testing with several different friend accounts, some of them see the stream on the user's timeline, other friends do not.

What are we doing wrong? Is there a privacy setting we are missing? Does facebook have other implicit rules around live streaming that we are not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You can not specify a privacy setting that is broader, than the *default* the user has set for anything published by your application.

When you ask for any publishing permission the first time, the user gets to select what privacy level they want to apply for content posted via your app, that looks something like this:

[image]

If the user sets this to “Only me” (or any other restrictive level, that is not fully public), then this is the maximum visibility level for all content the user publishes via your app. You can not go above that by specifying a broader privacy level in your API call, you can only limit it more. (Like, say, you could specify “only friends”, if the user set the default privacy level for your app to “public”.)

So you might have to tell your app users that they have to pick an appropriate level, before they login. They can also change this afterwards via their settings, under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: While this comment is true, it does not look like that's the problem here. Even if a user explicitly sets a stream to "public" after it has been created by the API, some people do not see it. Sharing the link to the streams results in a content not available error page. These people are also already friends. I am wondering if it has to do with the networks parameter in the privacy settings. The documentation does not say much about it, except that the value of "1" stands for "all networks".